# Firebase in Web : A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
      console.log("Hurray ! signed in successfully !");
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
     console.log("Sign in required !");
     $("#login-btn-nav").click();
  }
});



$("#login-btn").on('click',function(){
    console.log("Hello");
    var email = $("#email-input").val();
    var password = $("#password-input").val();

    if(email != "" && password != ""){
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
      window.alert("Following error encountered : "+errorMessage+" .");
    });
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDAvfWcdBTtmDbK7_aOkWFCRxNl1K4PDck",
    authDomain: "sarahhah-8e315.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://sarahhah-8e315.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "sarahhah-8e315",
    storageBucket: "sarahhah-8e315.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "965679781332"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  console.log(config);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
```

copied the web code snipets ans pasted in the html code as attached and javascript code is also attached !
facing error as :

A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. .

in web integration of firebase

thanks in advance for your cooperation

Comment: This app is hosted on firebase-hosting ? you enable the Email/password sign-in method ?

Comment: Error resolved  , used div tag instead of the form tag

Comment: @RahulSharma OMG! Thank you! Why would placing the input fields in a "form" tag result in a network error in Firebase? Does the HTML markup have any influence on the request? Or on the Javascript function? Why?

For everyone else: Remove your "form" tags around your "input" elements and it will work.

Comment: I changed but again I am getting  the same error

Comment: This is so weird, I do not have any `form` tag anywhere in my angular project. Even then I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will duplicate an answer from comments from [Rahul Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8147015/rahul-sharma) because this saved me a lot of time. Hope this will help somebody else:

Use `<div>` instead of `<form>` tag